# Application of Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I am considering the integral $\int_a^{\infty}f(t)\cos(\omega t)dt$ and I want to find the asymptotic expansion using the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma where as $\omega\rightarrow \infty$, $a,\omega$ real $f(t)$ is $C^\infty$ and $f^{(s)}(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$

I am litte bit confused here because I know that $\int_a^{b}f(t)e^{ikt}dt\sim\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{(ik)^{n+1}}(f^{(n)}(b)e^{ikb}-f^{(n)}(a)e^{ika})$ where we assume that $f(t)$ has $N+1$ contin. derivatives and $f^{(N+2)}$ is piecewise contin on $[a,b]$.

I also know that $e^{i\omega t}=\cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)$ but can I connect these things?

Comment: The expansion you give for $\int f(t)e^{ikt}$ seems to only be valid in the case that $k \to \infty$, but in the question you say you're concerned with the case $\omega \to 0$.  If $f \in L_1[a,\infty)$ then it follows from the dominated convergence theorem that $$\lim_{\omega \to 0} \int_a^\infty f(t)\cos(\omega t)\,dt = \int_a^\infty f(t)\,dt.$$  Is this what you're looking for, or do you actually mean to look at the case $\omega \to \infty$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake out, yes $\omega\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: In that case I think you could instead use the identity $\cos(\omega t) = \frac{1}{2}\left( e^{i\omega t} + e^{-i\omega t}\right)$.  Then you have two integrals of the form needed to apply the given result.

Comment: Ok,I have two questions; First, isnt there a problem then with writing $\infty$ instead of $b$? We do not know anything abou $f^{(n)}(\infty)$.
Secondly, what happens if $a=0, f^{(2s+1)}(a)=0?$

Comment: But one of the assumptions you're given is that $f^{(n)}(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, no?  And if $a = 0$ then $f^{(n)}(a) = f^{(n)}(0)$ and there's nothing more you can say without further assumptions.

Comment: If you'd like, I think it would be good to post your answer to this question.  I'll reimburse you for your 50 rep bounty with a bounty of my own :)

Comment: Will do that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the integral of $\cos$ over one period is zero. In the case of large $ω$, $\cos(ωt)$ has the very small period $\frac{2\pi}ω$. Since $f$ is smooth, it can be considered almost constant over such a period, suggesting that the integral is zero.

To rule out the obvious, and make the intuitive statement exact, use the already discussed partial integration method,
$$
\int_a^\infty f(t)\cos(ωt)dt=\left[f(t)\tfrac{\sin(ωt)}{ω}\right]_a^\infty-\int_a^\infty f'(t)\tfrac{\sin(ωt)}{ω}dt
$$
which allows to write 
$$
\left|\int_a^\infty f(t)\cos(ωt)dt\right|\le\frac1ω\left(|f(a)|+\int_a^\infty |f'(t)|\right)dt
$$
which allows to conclude the convergence to $0$ if $f'\in L^1$, or by repeating the partial integration, if any $f^{(n)}\in L^1$.